# Multiple Triggers on STM32 timer

Tags: timer, stm32

Is it possible to have multiple triggers on a stm32 timer? (TIM2 on STM32f4)

I have a timer that is periodically getting reset by an edge on a timer channel. Now I need to reset this same timer using an interrupt signal (also an edge). This interrupt can happen at any time.

Is this possible?

[image]

I have tried the following: With timer 2 you can redirect the output of the trigger detection on a channel to a different channel. I was thinking of configuring channel 2 to TI1FP1 and doing the same for channel 1 and triggering on the TI1FP1 channel but that does't seem to be doing a reset.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset any timer by update event: set bit **UG** in register **TIMx_EGR** usually it's bit 0.

[image]

For additional control interrupt and ARR, PSC, CCRx registers update rules see register **TIMx_CR1** bits **URS** and **UDIS**.

Comment: But this software reset right? I have very tight timing constraints. The timer is clocked at 32MHz so resetting the timer trough software would be too slow. I'm currently using the XOR feature of the timer to have multi-channel reset and it seems to be working but I assume things will go wrong if both channels reset at the same time; do you have any experience regarding using the XOR?

Comment: Yes it's software reset. I have no experience with timers XOR function but I think as you, that it's will be wrong behavior when both channels get edge. I have work with timer synchronization and I see one way that may be helpful: you can try to reset timer (configuerd as slave) by event from another (configured as master with generating _compare pulse_ event)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be sufficient to use channel1 as trigger and on the board route the signals to this pins as the design of the timer doesn't allow this.
Check also STM32F334 as it has HRTIM which allow really broad configuration options.